# Analyzing why more number of string objects are held up in the memory while profiling my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have been profiling my application for a high CPU issue(CPU clocking around 80% during load test). One of the feed back that we got from the MS Support team is that the Full GC has been running every 2seconds and that is CPU intensive and they mentioned there are many string objects being created. Hence, I have been profiling the application using ANTS profiler and I see the html markup that we are dynamically rendering in a custom web control are being held up in the memory(shown by ANTS profiler). Even if the string that we dynamically binding to button onclick event is being held onto the memory.

E.g:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return ValidateTheWorksheet('Default');");
}
```

In the above code, ANTS profiler shows String `"return ValidateTheWorksheet('Default');"` is held up onto the memory even after the page is completely rendered.

ANTS profiler support says that every memory snapshot does a full GC collection. Then Why is that string coming up in the memory?

Any advise would be helpful...

Thanks

Comment: Can you possibly show us the graph of the string from ANTS? It should show you what's holding references to it, and how far from GC Root it is.

Comment: Is the button still clickable? It would keep the string alive if so, I'd have thought.

Comment: I got an answer from MS feedback that the "return ValidateTheWorksheet('Default');" is just a string literal and that exists in the memory all the time. But, that will not affect GC at all...That seems to be right, and ANTS profile just picks it up from the memory and shows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. It was found to be one of the dependent team's reusable code, where they had a linq query and within the linq query they were doing string comparison using ToUpper and Trim function.

As, it will be in a loop for the entire list, the piece of the logic was CPU expensive.

Thanks